# How can i search for a value in a multi-dimensional array in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

this is my array:

```
0: {value: "VALUE1", label: "VALUE1"}
1: {value: "VALUE2", label: "VALUE2"}
```

I want to search for a value `truck` in this array, if found i need to run a function, else another function

Comment: This is not a "multi dimensional array", but just an array of objects. other than that: `if (yourArray.some(item => item.value === 'truck')) { // do whatever you need }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some . Otherwise, you can also use `Array.find` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

```js
function find(value, array) {
  for(data of array) {
    if(data['value'] === value) {
      return data
    }
  }
  return null
}

const result = find('truck', [
  { value: "VALUE1", label: "VALUE1" },
  { value: "VALUE2", label: "VALUE2" },
  { value: "truck", label: "VALUE2" }
])

if (result) {
  console.log('found a truck', { result })
} else {
  console.log('no truck found')
}
```